# create index page using stimulsoft report generator

Tags: c#, .net, report

Im using Stimulsoft for generating report.
I want to create an index page like books in the first pages that references the content with page number. how can i do this ??

Comment: who ever vote that down should give a comment what is wrong?
@Ehsan give us a bit more infomation what you've got so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Stimulsoft Documentation](http://www.stimulsoft.com/Documentation.aspx), download the Universal User Manual (pdf or chm) and look up section "3.33.1 Bookmarks" and "3.33.3 Reports with Contents".  This might be what you are looking for.